# flow-type import types from external file - name is already bound

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have the following component:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';

import TEA_DATA from './Tea.data';
import TeaInfo from './TeaInfo.component';

const Tea = () => <TeaInfo teaData={TEA_DATA}/>;

export default Tea;
```

Then I have the following Tea.data.types.js file:

```
// @flow

export type id = string;
export type image = string;
export type header = string;
export type text = Array<string>;
export type brewTime = Array<any>;

export type TEA_DATA = {
  id: id,
  image: image,
  header: header,
  text: text,
  brewTime: brewTime
};
```

And then I have the following tea.data.js file:

```
// @flow

import black from '../images/blacktea.png';
import white from '../images/whitetea.png';
import oolong from '../images/oolongtea.png';
import green from '../images/greentea.png';

import type TEA_DATA from './Tea.data.types';

const TEA_DATA = [{
  id: 'wtid',
  image: white,
  header: 'White tea',
  text: [
    "Currently there is no generally accepted definition of white tea and very little international agreement - some sources use the term to refer to tea that is merely dried with no additional processing, some to tea made from the buds and immature tea leaves picked shortly before the buds have fully opened and allowed to wither and dry in natural sun,[citation needed] while others include tea buds and very young leaves which have been steamed or fired before drying. Most definitions agree, however, that white tea is not rolled or oxidized, resulting in a flavour characterized as \"lighter\" than green or traditional black teas.",
    "In spite of its name, brewed white tea is pale yellow. Its name derives from the fine silvery-white hairs on the unopened buds of the tea plant, which give the plant a whitish appearance. It is harvested primarily in China, mostly in the Fujian province, but more recently produced in Eastern Nepal, Taiwan, Northern Thailand, Galle (Southern Sri Lanka) and India."
  ],
  brewTime: {
    mild: 1,
    strong: 3
  }
}...];

export default TEA_DATA;
```

According to the [flow docs](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types/) this is the correct way to import data types, but I am getting the following error:

> src/Tea/Tea.data.js:10  10: const TEA_DATA = [{
>              ^^^^^^^^ TEA_DATA. name is already bound   8: import type TEA_DATA from './Tea.data.types';
>                    ^^^^^^^^ type TEA_DATA
>
> src/Tea/Tea.data.js:58  58: export default TEA_DATA;
>                       ^^^^^^^^ TEA_DATA. type referenced from value position   8: import type TEA_DATA from './Tea.data.types';
>                    ^^^^^^^^ type TEA_DATA

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to name your type something different. Flow does not allow you to have both a type and a value with the same name in the same scope. You have imported the type `TEA_DATA` and you have also named a constant `TEA_DATA` in the same file.

Also, in this case you should use

```
import type {TEA_DATA} from './Tea.data.types';
```

(note the curly braces for destructuring) so that you import only the type `TEA_DATA` and not the whole module.